# Full package name instead of folder in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.2

**FIXED IN AS 2.2.1**

---

After update Android Studio to the 2.2 I've got this problem. It's hard to use such format with a small 13-inch display.

In Project view and Android view I get folders name as full packages name but I want to see just names of the directories:
[image: screenshot of the project window]

I tried to search for this problem, but I only find "Compact empty middle packages" which impact only for a top level folder.

"Flatten packages" option creates tons of the directories, for every package making everything even worse:

[image: flatten packages]

One more screenshot:

[image: with settings screen]

Comment: Above "Compact empty middle packages", there is "Flatten packages", which is probably checked on your machine. Uncheck it and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare no, it's not checked, if I check it, it starts to look even more awful

Comment: That's odd. I only get the behavior seen in your screenshot if "Flatten packages" is checked.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've added picture, how it looks like when I change Flatten packages :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the `Package`/ `Project` or `Android`view etc, Go to the gear icon on the right side and uncheck `Flatten Packages` and `Compact Empty Middle Packages`. This should show you the break down by directory instead of flattening it.

Note: This has now been fixed in Android Studio 2.2.1

[image]

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: Can u try clearing the cache and restart the AS? It's under File menu?

Comment: Do you happen to enable Data binding? As mentioned in the post below, with the latest update I see this happening when data binding is enabled. When data binding is disabled. It is working as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I use, that's really sad that this amazing framework is the reason

Comment: Yeah, according to Yigit, it needs to be there for now. Hopefully there will be  a fix later as it prioritized as "Priority-High Priority-Critical "

Comment: This has now been fixed on AS 2.2.1. It now works as expected.

Comment: That's great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AOSP - Issue Tracker:
Project structure view is showing full package names for sub packages when data binding is enabled.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222914

Answer (score 0):

Check this configuration if `Flatten Packages` is not your desired solution:

[image]

Hope it will help