# In Project View, can I just show files, not classes?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

New to Android Studio. While I understand the usefulness of the way the project explorer shows all objects within a Java file, sometimes I just want to see the files themselves within the folder structure, nothing else.  In other words, what a file explorer would show with no knowledge of Java at all.

Yes, I understand if the file has the same name as the contained class and that's the only thing in it, then I'll just see one node representing that class/file, but that will have the class name only, no file extension, and if we needed to add anything else in it, like an enum, then we're right back to the file as a node (with the .java extension!), then those objects all underneath it as child nodes.

Again, I just want to see 'MyFile.java' in the tree in its respective folder.  Nothing else.

Sidenote:

From what I've read, Jetbrains IntelliJ IDEA is from the same DNA as Android Studio, but the latter is optimized for (and only for) Android development.  Being more capable, would IntelliJ IDEA be an option to get what I want?

*Note: There are other questions on here that talk about navigation, etc.  I am not. I am specifically and **only** asking about the visual appearance of the tree in the project explorer.*

Comment: "In other words, what a file explorer would show with no knowledge of Java at all" -- that is largely what the Project view does (in contrast to other navigational options for that panel, such as Android or Packages). "if we needed to add anything else in it, like an enum, then we're right back to the file as a node" -- I cannot reproduce this in my copy of Android Studio. An enum inside a Java class does not show up in the Project navigation view. You might consider adding a screenshot or two to your question, illustrating what you are seeing.

Comment: In case you find yourself here, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733824/11071013) is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible de to select the project file view mode . On the upper left of Android studio, click on Android and select Project file .

Comment: Ironically, that still shows the items within the files which flies in the face of its name.

Comment: Oops sorry!Have you tried other options like e.g "Projet"?

Comment: Yes. They all seem to show/hide different groups of files, but the way it displays the files themselves seem to work the same.  Have you seen any that work the way I want?